# Error when filtering order by date in Magento 1

Tags: sales-order, mailchimp

Hi i am getting this error after i filter the order by date on magento here is the screenshot:
[image]

Actually, I recently added **mailchimp extension** & that is causing the problem with **magento 1.9** is anyone aware of a solution?

Comment: Disable compilation in your site and clear cache and test.

Comment: i did everything clear cache , disable compiler but still getting error when i click on sales order page.

Comment: As per your screenshot it seems your compilation is on.
Also can u disable raveinfosys delete order extention and test again?

Comment: no i cant do that i need some other solutions

Comment: Its for test. So you will get exact idea where the issue is.

Comment: @rehanansari  Have you solve issues or you need any help on this.?

Comment: no i am still not able to fix the issue @Emipro

Comment: ok i have fixed the issues by removing this query from code thanks every one

Answer (score 1):

The query doesn't understand from which table the 'created_at' field in WHERE  clause should be considered.
Find out the area and add the corresponding table alias to it, like main_table.created_at.

Probably the mailchimp extension has overridden the orders grid block.

EDIT:
Override your Sales order Grid Block 'Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid' and modify the 'created_at' column to the following

```
$this->addColumn('created_at', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased On'),
        'index' => 'created_at',
        'type' => 'datetime',
        'width' => '100px',
        'filter_index' => 'main_table.created_at'
    ));
```

Here we are adding a 'filter_index' to remove the ambiguous error.

Comment: yes its mailchimp extension but i dont know how to fix this query

Comment: Please see the updated answer

Comment: where is this file loacted?

Comment: i have fixed the issue thanks for your help.

Comment: @rehan ansari Great to know the issue is fixed :)

Comment: @rehanansari Please upvote my answer